# Restore marklogic database by extracting config from backup

Tags: database, backup, marklogic, restore

I have been given a copy of a Marklogic v9 database backup which was taken from a Marklogic server running on linux.

I now need to restore the database from the backup dump, onto a windows 2016 server, but the MarkLogic database on the destination windows server doesnt exist.

Is it possible to somehow extract the MarkLogic database configuration from the backup dump , create a database on the destination server then restore over that database?  In the backup dump I have a forests directory and all the XML/cfg/label files in the root directory of backup dump.

Or do I need a MarkLogic admin to extract the config of prod database that was backed up, then create an empty database on the destination server ( using the extracted prod database config ), then restore over that? I notice you cant restore without an existing database to restore over.

Or do I alternatively create a dummy database on my destination server of the same name as the prod database, then restore over that? The disk layout obviously will be different.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot restore a backup from a different architecture. If you need to move from Linux to Windows, I'd recommend using MLCP export/import, or maybe even copy. In any case you will need to have a target database up and running. You could export the configuration from one system, and import it in the other using our REST apis, like [Configuration Management API](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v3) or Management API. Our community tool [ML-Gradle](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle) could be of help with that.

HTH!

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. OK, I will need to run up a Linux box,thats fine - do I need to have a blank database with same structure and the same name as the original database? Or whenj I restore will marklogic just create the database from scratch and copy in the data e.g. like SQL Server does?

Comment: Sorry...found out I can only edit my answers for 5 mins.... a better worded response is : will MarkLogic just create the database from scratch on the server we are restoring to - using the disks its already sitting on and then copy in the data, forests etc ? Or is it super fussy and need to have all disks etc exactly the same as where it was backed up from? It would be super helpful to have a guide for this sort of stuff ( with examples ) in the ML official doco.

Comment: This would be a nice new question, but the answer is in the following link. Create the database first, with at least one forest. Pick 'Forest topology changed' when restoring, and instruct which forests data must go where: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/backup_restore#id_49850

Comment: Thank you - it turns out I may not have the option of running up a new Linux box, which means a different solution -  I will be posting a new question about copying a database from Linux ML to Windows ML soon.